# Android:Manage current state of fragment loaded which is not added to backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

My main activity xml file has a frame layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And I have added fragments in this way:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment,new AFragment(),"AFRAGMENT")
                    .commit();
```

Now problem is that Suppose A,B,C,D are the fragments and from A->B->C .
 Now on C ;I rotate the screen so activity is recreated.
Now I want to load C; however A will be loaded by default.
How to persist the current loaded fragment?

Comment: use add fragment instead of replace and give different tag for each fragments..And you can find each fragment by its tag..

Comment: sunil sunny if I use 20 fragments then in that case I have to put 20 if else, you mean?